# Prevent Automatic Logout of application

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-boot, web-applications, sign

I am using spring boot java web-application, after getting logged in,it gets logged out after some time if there is any inactivity how can I stop this? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify how long before the session timeout occurs because your experiencing one already your easiest resolution would be to locate web.xml file in the WEB-INF and change or remove the given timeout amount. If one for some reason it got deleted or is not there use the following to remake the web.xml file in the WEB-INF directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
        id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
   
  <display-name>YourWebAppName</display-name>
   
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
   
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
   
</web-app>
```

Comment: Thank you but I am not using any xml file,I am using gradle.